Apply constraints of Pan Tilt Zoom to Camera without the stream pausing for a little while
So i am in a bit of a pickle I am using WebRTC to control the PTZ functions of acamera using buttons for movement and zooming.
const constraints = {
    video: {
      pan: true,
      tilt: true,
      zoom: true
    }
  };

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
const [videoTrack] = stream.getVideoTracks();
const capabilities = videoTrack.getCapabilities();

After setting the current state where the camera should be I use
const constraints = { advanced: [{ [command]: adjustedValue }] };
await track.applyConstraints(constraints);

the problem is that this pauses my stream as the camera moves, in around 300-600ms the stream runs again in case of a longer movements its restored while the camera is still moving.
I kinda dont want to use OnVif or any HTTP based solution for this. Is there any way for PTZ controls in browser using the WebRTC but without pausing the stream

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Yogi That example is exactly how I did it and I have the same issue as that code e.g if you tilt or pan the stream of the PTZ camera gets stuck for a brief moment

if it reproduces on https://ptz.glitch.me/ it is most likely a driver issue as pointed out below.

I believe it is the camera hardware that is pausing the video feed during ptz movements. I can't reproduce with other Logitech cameras for example.
Which camera do you use by curiosity?
